# JMeter NonGUI Error : java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, jmeter, jmx

I am trying to run JMeter thru Java Code (using Runtime.exe) but getting following error:
I am creating new process thru Java using jmeter.bat

Here are the arguments: C:\apache-jmeter-2.8\bin\jmeter.bat -n -t C:\test\test.jmx -l C:\test\test.log

Please help!

```
2014/09/10 18:05:25 ERROR - jmeter.save.SaveService: Conversion error com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException:  : no more data available - expected end tags </elementProp></collectionProp></elementProp></HTTPSamplerProxy></hashTree></hashTree></hashTree></hashTree></jmeterTestPlan> to close start tag <elementProp> from line 1 and start tag <collectionProp> from line 1 and start tag <elementProp> from line 1 and start tag <HTTPSamplerProxy> from line 1 and start tag <hashTree> from line 1 and start tag <hashTree> from line 1 and start tag <hashTree> from line 1 and start tag <hashTree> from line 1 and start tag <jmeterTestPlan> from line 1, parser stopped on END_TAG seen ...</stringProp>        ... @1:1966080 :  : no more data available - expected end tags </elementProp></collectionProp></elementProp></HTTPSamplerProxy></hashTree></hashTree></hashTree></hashTree></jmeterTestPlan> to close start tag <elementProp> from line 1 and start tag <collectionProp> from line 1 and start tag <elementProp> from line 1 and start tag <HTTPSamplerProxy> from line 1 and start tag <hashTree> from line 1 and start tag <hashTree> from line 1 and start tag <hashTree> from line 1 and start tag <hashTree> from line 1 and start tag <jmeterTestPlan> from line 1, parser stopped on END_TAG seen ...</stringProp>        ... @1:1966080
---- Debugging information ----
message             :  : no more data available - expected end tags </elementProp></collectionProp></elementProp></HTTPSamplerProxy></hashTree></hashTree></hashTree></hashTree></jmeterTestPlan> to close start tag <elementProp> from line 1 and start tag <collectionProp> from line 1 and start tag <elementProp> from line 1 and start tag <HTTPSamplerProxy> from line 1 and start tag <hashTree> from line 1 and start tag <hashTree> from line 1 and start tag <hashTree> from line 1 and start tag <hashTree> from line 1 and start tag <jmeterTestPlan> from line 1, parser stopped on END_TAG seen ...</stringProp>        ... @1:1966080
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.StreamException
cause-message       :  : no more data available - expected end tags </elementProp></collectionProp></elementProp></HTTPSamplerProxy></hashTree></hashTree></hashTree></hashTree></jmeterTestPlan> to close start tag <elementProp> from line 1 and start tag <collectionProp> from line 1 and start tag <elementProp> from line 1 and start tag <HTTPSamplerProxy> from line 1 and start tag <hashTree> from line 1 and start tag <hashTree> from line 1 and start tag <hashTree> from line 1 and start tag <hashTree> from line 1 and start tag <jmeterTestPlan> from line 1, parser stopped on END_TAG seen ...</stringProp>        ... @1:1966080
class               : org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.TestElementProperty
required-type       : org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.TestElementProperty
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.TestElementPropertyConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[3]/HTTPSamplerProxy[154]/elementProp/collectionProp/elementProp[41]
line number         : 1
class[1]            : org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.CollectionProperty
converter-type[1]   : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.MultiPropertyConverter
class[2]            : org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy
converter-type[2]   : org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBaseConverter
class[3]            : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type[3]   : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter
------------------------------- :  : no more data available - expected end tags </elementProp></collectionProp></elementProp></HTTPSamplerProxy></hashTree></hashTree></hashTree></hashTree></jmeterTestPlan> to close start tag <elementProp> from line 1 and start tag <collectionProp> from line 1 and start tag <elementProp> from line 1 and start tag <HTTPSamplerProxy> from line 1 and start tag <hashTree> from line 1 and start tag <hashTree> from line 1 and start tag <hashTree> from line 1 and start tag <hashTree> from line 1 and start tag <jmeterTestPlan> from line 1, parser stopped on END_TAG seen ...</stringProp>        ... @1:1966080 :  : no more data available - expected end tags </elementProp></collectionProp></elementProp></HTTPSamplerProxy></hashTree></hashTree></hashTree></hashTree></jmeterTestPlan> to close start tag <elementProp> from line 1 and start tag <collectionProp> from line 1 and start tag <elementProp> from line 1 and start tag <HTTPSamplerProxy> from line 1 and start tag <hashTree> from line 1 and start tag <hashTree> from line 1 and start tag <hashTree> from line 1 and start tag <hashTree> from line 1 and start tag <jmeterTestPlan> from line 1, parser stopped on END_TAG seen ...</stringProp>        ... @1:1966080
---- Debugging information ----
message             :  : no more data available - expected end tags </elementProp></collectionProp></elementProp></HTTPSamplerProxy></hashTree></hashTree></hashTree></hashTree></jmeterTestPlan> to close start tag <elementProp> from line 1 and start tag <collectionProp> from line 1 and start tag <elementProp> from line 1 and start tag <HTTPSamplerProxy> from line 1 and start tag <hashTree> from line 1 and start tag <hashTree> from line 1 and start tag <hashTree> from line 1 and start tag <hashTree> from line 1 and start tag <jmeterTestPlan> from line 1, parser stopped on END_TAG seen ...</stringProp>        ... @1:1966080
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.StreamException
cause-message       :  : no more data available - expected end tags </elementProp></collectionProp></elementProp></HTTPSamplerProxy></hashTree></hashTree></hashTree></hashTree></jmeterTestPlan> to close start tag <elementProp> from line 1 and start tag <collectionProp> from line 1 and start tag <elementProp> from line 1 and start tag <HTTPSamplerProxy> from line 1 and start tag <hashTree> from line 1 and start tag <hashTree> from line 1 and start tag <hashTree> from line 1 and start tag <hashTree> from line 1 and start tag <jmeterTestPlan> from line 1, parser stopped on END_TAG seen ...</stringProp>        ... @1:1966080
class               : org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.TestElementProperty
required-type       : org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.TestElementProperty
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.TestElementPropertyConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[3]/HTTPSamplerProxy[154]/elementProp/collectionProp/elementProp[41]
line number         : 1
class[1]            : org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.CollectionProperty
converter-type[1]   : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.MultiPropertyConverter
class[2]            : org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy
converter-type[2]   : org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBaseConverter
class[3]            : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type[3]   : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter

..................................
........................
..............


2014/09/10 18:05:25 ERROR - jmeter.JMeter: Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeModel.addSubTree(JMeterTreeModel.java:93)
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.runNonGui(JMeter.java:744)
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.startNonGui(JMeter.java:722)
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.start(JMeter.java:386)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:216)
```

Answer (score 2):

Either your xml file is corrupt or is not xml.

Check it.

What versions of jmeter and java are you using ?

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue by parsing XML which was input to method as string by using DocumentBuilderFactory and other API. Thanks for your response.